# Client-side JavaScript astronomy libraries which are not based on node.js?

Tags: positional-astronomy, javascript

Are there any *client-side* JavaScript astronomy libraries? Almost every library I see appears to be server side for node.js. I realize some node.js libraries can be adapted for client-side use, so I'd also be happy with a server-side library that happens to work client-side as well.

EDIT: I did find https://github.com/mourner/suncalc but it appears to be abandoned, has 35+ open issues, many related to accuracy, and, despite its description, appears to give only solar and lunar positions, not planetary positions.

Comment: What are your expectations/requirements to such a library? Calculating "things", animating objects? For solar systems, the Milkyway, the observable universe? Please be more specific.

Comment: For right now, it's just a general question. Obviously, I'd want "the most complete" library eventually, but, for now, I'll settle for anything.

Comment: I think it wouldn't be so hard to extract the computing part of the server-side node.js libs.

Comment: @peterhsaysreinstateMonica I actually tried this with orb.js and livestreamed my attempt at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v1ItMdi3_GY but it's harder than it looks, especially when file loading is involved. Of course, you're free to take a shot.

Answer (score 1):

I found "Astronomy" from "cosinekitty" on Github:

https://github.com/cosinekitty/astronomy

It supports both node.js and browser.

Browser demos:

https://github.com/cosinekitty/astronomy/tree/master/demo/browser

**Testing the library without downloading whole repository:**

Save this file locally:

https://github.com/cosinekitty/astronomy/blob/master/demo/browser/positions.html

Into the file, replace line

```
<script src="astronomy.browser.js"></script>
```

by

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cosinekitty/astronomy@1.0.1/source/js/astronomy.js"></script>
```

Reference: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/cosinekitty/astronomy/

Change this line:

```
let observer = new Astronomy.Observer(latitude, longitude, elevation);
```

to

```
let observer = new Astronomy.MakeObserver(latitude, longitude, elevation);
```

Remove line:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="astro_demo.css" />
```

You should get the table in the file filled up with data calculated by the library.

---

Another one is [astronomy-bundle-js](https://github.com/andrmoel/astronomy-bundle-js):

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/andrmoel/astronomy-bundle-js@6.0.4/src

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely checkout "astronomy-bundle"

https://www.npmjs.com/package/astronomy-bundle

This library covers most of the important astronomical calculations and has a great documentations.